# Setting font-size for all text except <h1> <h2> etc

Tags: html, css

I'm applying CSS to a box of my page which may contain `<div>` `<table>` `<p>` and other elements, and just plain text.

I want all the text to be the same font size, with exception for text within tags such as `<h1>` `<h2>` `<h3>`

With objectid "mybox" my simple CSS font modifier was

```
.mybox * {
font-size: 13px;
}
```

The problem is that this also sets the font for any `<h2>` elements and so on.
I could add a class to my `<h2>` elements and another selector to override the font size again, but that feels very backwards.

What is a good way to take care of this?

I found the not() selector which works for classes, but I couldn't find one for html elements like `<h2>` to exclude them from my "global" font modifier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector with those *"unwanted"* elements:

```css
.mybox *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3) {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
  <h1>foo</h1>
  <h2>bar</h2>
  <h3>Hans</h3>
  <label>Gruber</label>
  <p>Goku</p>
  <div>Yoda</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvnkoe57/)

Comment: Sorry, just forget it

Comment: Also, it's better to use as a single line - `.mybox *:not(h1):not(h2):not(h3){...}`

Answer (score 3):

you can set your font style on the `body` and add `:not(h1):not(h2)` for not include style on them.

Answer (score 1):

Set the desired text size in the `body` and then what ever you desire for the headers:

```css
body{
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1{
  font-size: 50px;
}

h2{
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>
<h1>header 1</h1>
<h2>header 2</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others suggested, there are primarily 2 ways of doing this, either by adding a  `:not` selector to your `h1` and `h2` tags, or simply giving those tags a separate font-size.

```
.mybox:not(h1):not(h2) {
   font-size: 14pt;
}
```

Alternatively, and what I would do, is take advantage of CSS cascading nature. This means that any properties you give to an element overrides any previous properties you may have given it. So here's how to do that:

```
body {
  font-size: 12pt;
}

.mybox h1 {
  font-size: 18pt;
}

.mybox h2 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}
```

Here, it's important to declare the `body` properties first, and then the `h1` and `h2` tags.