# Setting font for all text except a class css

Tags: html, css

Here is the css I'm using

```
html:not(.stylenotneeded), body:not(.stylenotneeded), form, fieldset, table, tr, td, img {
   font: 100%/150% calibri;
}
```

and the html is

```
<div class="stylenotneeded">
  <font face="Impact" size="9" color="8C003D"><b>Some Text</b></font><br>
  <font face="verdana" size="4" color="8C003D"><b>Sometext 2</b></font>
</div>

<div>
  <font face="Impact" size="9" color="8C003D"><b>Some Text</b></font><br>
  <font face="verdana" size="4" color="8C003D"><b>Sometext 2</b></font>
</div>
```

**I want the `font-style` in the `css` to be applied on all the text except the `stylenotneeded` div portion.**

Already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177956/setting-font-size-for-all-text-except-h1-h2-etc) without any luck.

Can someone please help me out on this?

Comment: `font` tag overrides `css`

Answer (score 1):

```css
div:not(.stylenotneeded) font, 
form,
fieldset,
table,
tr,
td,
img {
   font: 100%/150% calibri;
}
```

```html
<div class="stylenotneeded">
  <font face="Impact" size="9" color="8C003D"><b>Some Text</b></font><br>
  <font face="verdana" size="4" color="8C003D"><b>Sometext 2</b></font>
</div>

<div>
  <font face="Impact" size="9" color="8C003D"><b>Some Text</b></font><br>
  <font face="verdana" size="4" color="8C003D"><b>Sometext 2</b></font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a lot of deprecated code. You need to set a default set of properties for font, for your document, then you can overwrite whatever elements you want, with(i.e) a class name:

```
body{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
}

.stylenotneeded{
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight:700;
}
.stylenotneeded b{
    color:#8C003D;
    font-size:9px;
}
```

And you html can be easily cleaner, and separated from your styles:

```
<div class="stylenotneeded">
  <b>Some Text</b><br>
  <b>Sometext 2</b>
</div>
```